# Make axis animate adding new items with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a horizontal axis which takes a scale as input:

```
    xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(_.range(bars.length))
        .rangeRoundBands([0, 500]);
```

[image: Two items added on the right]

I wonder if it's possible to make those two items added on the right animate in the same way as existing ones?

I want new items appear like here happens for vertical axis: [vertical axis animation](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4323929)

Comment: not sure about that... in the example you provide the domain changes completely (specially because the tick size is fixed)

Comment: First add the two new items to your chart. Render the chart. Given that the domain does not include those items, the chart will remain the same. Finally update the domain of the xScale and render the chart.

Comment: You can't easily with the axis component -- you'd need to modify the source of that.